# Jenkins. Using drop down button to select different options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I don´t know which plugin is best option for this. But I would like to have a build with parameters job in which I have only 2 options. Option-A and Option-B.

If I choose Option A,  nothing strange should happens and you can hit build button for starting job. Suppose that job only has `sh "echo hello"` 
But if I choose Option B (maybe some radio buttons), I would like that a textbox appears,  and that user enter a string value and starts job. then that value will be used in pipline to execute same command grabbing that value.

For example, If user entered in textbox PETER, Job would be:  sh "echo hello {$textvalue} (PETER).

I was able to do this with  simple groovy code like this and using String parameter.

```
def var1 = params.TEXT

node {

      stage('show text') {

          sh (""" echo hello $var1 """)


      }
```

[image]

But how Can I do this with a radio buttons options (or something similar)? . I tried with Active choice parameter and active choice reactive parameter. But this doesn´t accomplish what I want, which is to appear just a textbox if I choose option-A and just run the job and nothing shows up if you choose option-B.

thanks!

(EDITED)

[image]

[image]