# Active choice reactive parameter Hide name if no values are selected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there a Way of Hiding name before build with active choice reactive parameter? (in this case ID1, ID2 and ID3), I have configured a choice parameter and three active choice reactive parameters to enter some values in case that "values" option is selected. But I don´t want to show them in Jenkins UI if "no values" options  is selected.

[image]

This is how I have it configured. (Adding just ID1 but the others 2 -ID2 and ID3- are the same)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins. Using drop down button to select different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533879/jenkins-using-drop-down-button-to-select-different-options)

Comment: how exactly? where should I put : "setting e.g. display: none" Does this hide the name?
tks